# Can I format currency when sending email using google app Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I create a page with google Script for orders . When the order is finished, it will automatically save to Google sheet and email a copy to the customer (in normal email format/text). The money display for email I want to format is 1,000,000 (with commas).
The part I want to format is .

This is my code

```css
function doGet(e) {
var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
htmlOutput.message = '';
return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
.getContent();
}
/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
.getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10s7pV1Rv1jy--EQxVg-86ikNfj5KGmyfLdYwVO-Qpzs/edit#gid=0";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("注文リスト");

ws.appendRow(["H Guard社　インフル＆コロナ ダブル検査キット",
formObject.numberProductHGuard,
formObject.priceProductHGuard,

"DIAsia社　口腔内粘膜（唾液）コロナ検査キット",
formObject.numberProductDIAsia,
formObject.priceProductDIAsia,
formObject.sumprice,

formObject.YourCompany,
formObject.manager,
formObject.Email,
formObject.postnumber,
formObject.location,
formObject.telephonenumber,
formObject.Faxnumber,

"お届け先情報",
formObject.option2,
formObject.Companypart2,
formObject.managerpart2,
formObject.department2,
formObject.postnumberPart2,
formObject.locationpart2,
formObject.telephonenumberPart2,
formObject.Faxnumberpart2,

"ご請求先情報",
formObject.option3,
formObject.Companypart3,
formObject.managerpart3,
formObject.department3,
formObject.postnumberPart3,
formObject.locationpart3,
formObject.telephonenumberPart3,
formObject.Faxnumberpart3


]);
var html_body =   formObject.YourCompany+   "<br>" 
+formObject.manager +     "様<br><br>"
+"この度は新型コロナ関連抗原検査キットのご注文をいただき、誠にありがとうございます。"+"<br>"
+"ご注文をいただき、誠にありがとうございます。<br>"
+"２営業日以内に、折り返し弊社担当よりご注文の受付確認のご連絡を差し上げますので、しばらくお待ちください。<br>"
+"なお、2営業日経過後も弊社より連絡がない場合は、弊社にご注文内容が届いていない可能性がございます。<br>"

+"お手数をおかけしまして恐れ入りますが、お電話にてご注文の確認をお問い合わせください。<br>"
+"<h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>********************ご注文内容********************* </h3><br>"
+"商品名：H Guard社　インフル＆コロナ ダブル検査キット<br>"
+"商品数量："+formObject.numberProductHGuard+"ケース<br>"
+"金額："+formObject.priceProductHGuard+"円<br><br>"

+"商品名：DIAsia社　口腔内粘膜（唾液）コロナ検査キット<br>"
+"商品数量："+formObject.numberProductDIAsia+"ケース<br>"
+"金額："+formObject.priceProductDIAsia+"円<br>"
+"合計金額："+formObject.sumprice+"円<br><br><br>"

+"貴社名："+formObject.YourCompany+"<br>"
+"ご担当者名："+formObject.manager+"<br>"
+"郵便番号："+formObject.postnumber+"<br>"
+"所在地："+formObject.location+"<br>"
+"メールアドレス："+formObject.Email+"<br>"
+"お電話番号："+formObject.telephonenumber+"<br>"
+"FAX番号："+formObject.Faxnumber+"<br><br>"
+"━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━"

+"<h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>お届け先情報</h3><br>"
+"お届け先の指定："+formObject.option2+"<br>"
+"企業名：" +formObject.Companypart2+"<br>"
+"ご担当者名："+formObject.managerpart2+"<br>"
+"部署・役職："+formObject.department2+"<br>"
+"郵便番号："+formObject.postnumberPart2+"<br>"
+"所在地："+formObject.locationpart2+"<br>"
+"お電話番号："+formObject.telephonenumberPart2+"<br>"
+"FAX番号："+formObject.Faxnumberpart2+"<br>"
+"━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━"

+"<h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>＜ご請求先情報＞</h3><br>"
+"ご請求先の指定："+formObject.option3+"<br>"
+"企業名："+formObject.Companypart3+"<br>"
+"ご担当者名："+formObject.managerpart3+"<br>"
+"部署・役職："+formObject.department3+"<br>"
+"郵便番号："+formObject.postnumberPart3+"<br>"
+"所在地："+formObject.locationpart3+"<br>"
+"お電話番号："+formObject.telephonenumberPart3+"<br>"
+"FAX番号："+formObject.Faxnumberpart3+"<br><br>"
+"*****************************************************<br><br>"
+"このメールに心当たりの無い場合は、お手数ですが<br>"
+"下記連絡先までお問い合わせください。<br>"
+"この度はお問い合わせ重ねてお礼申し上げます。<br><br>"






MailApp.sendEmail({
to: formObject.Email,
subject: "新型コロナ関連抗原検査キットのご注文ありがとうございます／株式会社ミヤゲン",
body: "",
htmlBody: html_body
});






}
```

Comment: I thought that in your question when you provide the sample value of `formObject` and the sample output value, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Can you clarify the source value and format? Is the source value a [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure about your sample value of `formObject`, when you want to convert `123456789` to `123,456,789`, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
+"金額："+formObject.priceProductHGuard+"円<br><br>"
```

#### To:

```
+"金額："+formObject.priceProductHGuard.toLocaleString()+"円<br><br>"
```

And,

#### From:

```
+"金額："+formObject.priceProductDIAsia+"円<br>"
+"合計金額："+formObject.sumprice+"円<br><br><br>"
```

#### To:

```
+"金額："+formObject.priceProductDIAsia.toLocaleString()+"円<br>"
+"合計金額："+formObject.sumprice.toLocaleString()+"円<br><br><br>"
```

#### Note:

- I thought that in your situation, `locales` of `toLocaleString(locales)` might be required to be used. But if it is required to use it, please set it.
- If this was not the result you expect, can you provide the sample value of `formObject` and the sample output values? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)